# Icon Badge Number *without" a number

Tags: iphone, badge

Does anybody know how to show a badge without showing a number? Similar to when the phone app cannot get the count for visual voice mail?

For an example of what I mean see the following pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQupy.jpg

Comment: Wow is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomBadge class.... you can download it from [here](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/09/create-a-custom-iphone-ipad-badge/?lang=en)

Example:

```
// Create simple Badge with empty string
CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@" "];

// or change text programmatically 
[customBadge1 autoBadgeSizeWithString:@" "];
```